# How to trigger neighbour element to "this" object in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have 1 button - `<a>` link and list - ul. I need to show/hide list when I click on button. Here is the code:

```
<div class="wide-tile" id="tile-1">
    <div class="size-set">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"> > </a>
        <ul class="size-list">
            <li>1x1</li>
            <li>1x2</li>
            <li>2x1</li>
            <li>2x2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="details.html" class="wide-tile-link">
        <span class="title">About us</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The problem is: I have many tiles and each of it has same "set-size" class div.
When I press on  link I need to toggle ul list.
So far I've done on JQuery

```
$(".size-set").click(function(){
    $(".toggle-btn",this).click(function(){
        $(".size-list",this).toggle("slow","swing");
    });
});
```

It doesn't work, maybe because this `$(".size-list",this)` construction is used for parent and child class. What I need is same DOM level access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `$(".toggle-btn").click` separately and use [`$.fn.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get sibling `.size-list` to toggle. In this case you don't need click event on `.size-set` anymore:

```
$(".toggle-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".size-list").toggle("slow", "swing");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First bind click event separately, Then you can use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

*Code*

```
$(".toggle-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".size-list").toggle("slow", "swing");
});
```

---

As per your current HTML, You can also use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$(this).next(".size-list").toggle("slow","swing");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("size-set").on("click", ".toggle-btn", function(){
        $(this).closest("size-set").find(".size-list").toggle("slow","swing")
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got what to what to that's why I made 2 working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0ju32vqf/). I hope you find this helpful.

```
$("#tile-1 .size-set a.toggle-btn").click(function(e){
  $('#tile-1 .size-list, #tile-1 .size-set a.toggle-btn').toggle('slow','swing');      
e.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: That works perfectly, but here you define element by ID, so i have to write code for each button. That's why I failed to make it work if you have #title-1 ....#title-20. 
However, thank you.